# Simplify Javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, view, single-page-application

I am using object-oriented javascript to show/hide 'views' on click of the nav link and also on a button that is used to go to the next view.  I feel like this can definitely be simplified but I am not sure what the best way to do this is.  My html is as follows:

```
<div id="sidebar">
        <a href="/"><svg width="261" height="70"><use xlink:href="#logo"></use></svg></a>
        <nav>
            <ol>
                <li><a href="#"><span>1</span>Run your business</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>2</span>Let us work for you</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>3</span>Check your books</a></li>
            </ol>
        </nav>
        <a class="progress-btn main-btn visible" href="#">Start the demo</a>
        <a class="progress-btn main-btn" href="#">Next</a>
        <a class="progress-btn main-btn" href="#">Next</a>
        <a class="progress-btn main-btn" href="#">30-day free trial</a>
    </div><!--end sidebar-->

    <div id="content">
        <div class="page page1">
            <h2>Page 1</h2>
        </div><!--end page1-->
        <div class="page page2">
            <h2>Page 2</h2>
        </div><!--end page2-->
        <div class="page page3">
            <h2>Page 3</h2>
        </div><!--end page3-->
        <div class="page page4">
            <h2>Page 4</h2>
        </div><!--end page4-->
    </div><!--end content-->
```

And my object looks like this:

```
View = {
  page: '.page',
  mainLink: '#sidebar li a',
  progressButton: '.progress-btn',
  init: function() {
    $(this.mainLink).click(this.showView.bind(this));
    $(this.mainLink).click(this.activeNav.bind(this));
    $(this.progressButton).click(this.sidebarButton.bind(this));
  },
  showView: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(e.target),
      targetIndex = target.index(this.mainLink),
      pageToTarget = targetIndex + 2;
    $(this.page).removeClass("current").fadeOut('fast').promise().done(function() {
      $('.page' + pageToTarget).fadeIn().addClass("current");
    });
  },
  activeNav: function(e) {
    $(this.mainLink).removeClass("active");
    e.preventDefault();
    $(e.target).addClass("active");
    var targetIndex = $(e.target).index(this.mainLink)
    $(".progress-btn").removeClass("visible");
    $(".progress-btn").eq(targetIndex + 1).addClass("visible");
  },
  sidebarButton: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(e.target);
    targetIndex = target.index(this.progressButton);
    pageToTarget = targetIndex + 2;
    if (target.text() == "30-day free trial") {
      window.open("http://google.com");
    } else {
      target.removeClass("visible");
      target.next().addClass("visible");
      $(this.page).removeClass("current").fadeOut('fast').promise().done(function() {
        $('.page' + pageToTarget).fadeIn().addClass("current");
      });
      $(this.mainLink).removeClass("active");
      $("#sidebar li a").eq(targetIndex).addClass("active");
    }
    console.log(targetIndex);
    // pageRoute(targetIndex);
  }
}

View.init();
```

Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rsgLbgg3/4/.  How can I simplify this to work with both the nav and the button without being so repetitive.

Just learning to learn a little.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: For a start, you're not doing much object-oriented JS.  You should look into  binding your functions to the prototype and using a constructor.  Then you can instantiate your object with the `new` keyword.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @dustmouse, I try to use prototypes when I can, but don't see how that method would come into play here.

Comment: I don't see any repetition in the code.